# MultiColumn ComboBox population

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate a multi column combobox on a userform from data on a worksheet.

For a range of rows, if the first column is blank and the third column is not blank I want to store the third column value and row number into the combobox.  The code I have tried keeps throwing the error:

> Run-time error '381': Could not set the Column property. Invalid property array index

```
For x = 5 To i
If ws.Cells(x, 1) = "" And ws.Cells(x, 3) <> "" Then
    With ComboBox
        .Column(0, .ListCount) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
        .Column(1, .ListCount) = x
    End With
End If
Next x
```

The combobox has had its column count set to 2 in properties.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_The code I have tried keeps throwing back errors_" ... And what would those be?

Comment: When .Column(0, >ListCount......  is run I get:  Run-time error '381': Could not set the Column property. Invalid property array index.

Comment: I am assuming the error is because I am referring to a .Column but giving a Column and Row reference within the brackets.  I just don't know how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
.Column(0, .ListCount - 1) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
.Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = x
```

to address the last entry. This is becasue `.ListCount` returns the natural number of entries (0 if empty, 1 if 1 entry, etc), while `.Column()` behaves like 0 based arrays, so 1st entry is at `.Column(0,...)`.

**EDIT:**

You can use `.AddItem` to add 1 more row to combobox and then fill the values one by one like this:

```
ComboBox.AddItem
With ComboBox
    .Column(0, .ListCount - 1) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
    .Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = x
End With
```

Alternatively, you can fill an array with values and load it into the combobox in one step like this:

```
Dim cBuf(2, 0 to 2)
cBuf(0, 0) = "John"
cBuf(0, 1) = 1982
...
ComboBox = cBuf
```

Read more here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371892/how-to-create-two-columns-lookup-combobox-in-excel-vba-userform)

Comment: Thanks AcsErno.  The ComboBox is empty as the code runs.  So surely .ListCount will address the fist entry on the ComboBox?  I have tried adding in the -1 but it does not change the error.  Tried +1 also, without success.

Comment: I am afraid those suggestions haven't helped me.  The first suggestion still throws up the same error.  I'm not sure how to fill an array from my For loop at the moment, I will look into it.   I have also noticed that while debugging that if I hover over the problem line of code I get a tooltip of:  .Column(0, .ListCount) = <Object variable or With block variable not set>.

Answer (score 0):

So big thanks to AcsErno.  The solution to my problem was to create a new entry (.AddItem) for the ComboBox then to assign values to each column of the new entry.  My code now reads as below and works as I wanted.

```
For x = 5 To i
    If ws.Cells(x, 1) = "" And ws.Cells(x, 3) <> "" Then
        With ComboBox
            .AddItem
            .Column(0, .ListCount - 1) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
            .Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = x
        End With
     End If
Next x
```